# How to get length of Non-Overflow content of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have div, with large text content. and its showing content only inside the box by using `overflow:hidden`.

Now how can i get the length of (no of chars) this visbile content inside box, i.e, non-oveflown content.

Comment: when you say length of visible content.. do you mean number of characters in the text content you provided? or the width and height occupied by this text?

Comment: @abbood i want no of chars..only..

Comment: why was this question down voted? it's a perfectly valid question and has practical uses (ie when you want to determine where to place an ellipsis at the end of an article blurb that can expand with a 'read more' expand button for example.. I've used it for that purpose myself for some clients and I had to answer this precise question). Rishi I've voted you back up. For the party that downvoted, it would help us all if you share with us why you think this question is worth a down vote.

Comment: Rishi another question: suppose that part of the text is clipped out.. would you want to count those as well in your final result or not? see  this http://jsfiddle.net/yKd3L/ for an example of what i'm talking about. Perhaps if you explain what use will this number of char value be to you, then we can provide you with a more useful answer.

Comment: @abbood thanks for ur concern.. actually, i'm trying to text wrapping around image feel without using css properties like(float, postion, align). untill now i've done some progress.. just look at this.. http://jsfiddle.net/R7cZL/12/

Answer (score 0):

*There is no fool-proof way of detecting this.* The amount of visible text depends on the various factors like the font used, the line-height, letter-spacing etc. If the font is uniform through out the text and is mono-spaced then you can apply some math using char-width and height to get this, but it is unlikely to be perfect across browsers.

Comment: why would this be a cross browser problem if you are using a cross browser tool like jQuery to determine the widths of the characters etc? the result of width and height may vary across browsers.. but then again the methods handling these values should also account for the browser difference as well.. ie the cross browser problem would be a self cancelling one with jQuery etc

Answer (score 0):

If you have set a height on the `div`, you already have the number. But if you don't, you should get the height of `div` using JS functions.  No matter how much content is hidden, the height of `div` is what you can see.

Like all of other works in JS if you want to make it work on all browsers easily, you should use a framework.  In [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/), for example, you can call this:

```
$("DIV_ID").getHeight();
```

replacing `DIV_ID` with id attribute of the div.